# jQuery serialize + base64encode

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, base64

Is there a way to serialize a form so that the output would be base64 encoded?

With regards,

Mike.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a script like this one to base64 output the serialized form https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64

```
$.base64.encode($('form').serialize())
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can attach to the form IDs using

```
($('#NAMEOFID').serialize());
```

or

```
($('#NAMEOFID').serializeArray());
```

That puts it into a JSON serialized array, but I don't think jQuery has a built in base64 plugin (I may be wrong). I went ahead and found a base64 plugin: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/base64

Just pass it that serialized string, and that should work.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your comment!
thing is, i wanna maintain the serialized structure: a=base64&b=base64 and so on so that i could pass it to my mailing form.
was thinking of just getting the form values, encoding it on submit and then serializing it, but i'm looking for a more elegant way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [base64 encode library](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html), then:

```
var serialized = $('form').serialize();
var encoded = Base64.encode(serialized);
```